# primefaces fileUploadListener not invoked at Requestscope

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

fileupload listener not invoked in request scope

```
<p:fileUpload id="uploaded"
    fileUploadListener="#{travelRequestBean.handleFileUpload}"
    multiple="true" mode="advanced" sizeLimit="100000" 
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|docx|rar|zip)$/"
    update=":dataForm:imageDisplayPanel" />
```

Comment: Share your bean as well please

Comment: Are you sure that you have all libs including `commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar`, `commons-io-1.4.jar`

Comment: Also tell that Is it working when you change you bean scope to greater than `requestscope` mean `viewscope` or `sessionscope` etc

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Bad `web.xml` / `faces-config.xml` parameter? Is `p:fileUpload` inside a `h:form`? Are other components in the same form working?

Comment: its working in viewscope.

Comment: its present inside the form. 1st i saved the basic input details then upload the file. when i save the basic input details its saved then i upload the file its not working

Comment: faces-config.xml org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter included

Comment: @PonniMaran yes this is the issue.I have also this issue that listener was not working with Request scope but it was working with viewscope o rgreater.I dont know what is the reason but Anyway if you are OK with viewscope then I think you should happy now :)